# Django Python iterate attribute of object from list

Tags: python, django, list, object

i have a set of atributes stored on list, and i have an object called customuser, i want to iterate its attribute from the list and display value from database

```
fieldx={'department','usertype','company'}

for f in fieldx:
    print(customuser.f)
```

but i get the following error message:
'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'f'
can you help me with this
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use built-in [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)

```py
fieldx={'department','usertype','company'}

for f in fieldx:
    print(getattr(customuser, f))
```

Comment: many thanks for your help getattr solves the issue :)